# Multivariate Binary Classification Prediction Tensorflow 2 LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I am currently working on the implementation of an LSTM to predict a binary outcome (either 0 or 1) for a given set of normed scaled features.

```
    self._regressor.add(LSTM(units=60, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(data.x_train.shape[1], data.x_train.shape[2])))
    self._regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self._regressor.add(LSTM(units=60, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    self._regressor.add(Dropout(0.3))
    self._regressor.add(LSTM(units=80, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    self._regressor.add(Dropout(0.4))
    self._regressor.add(LSTM(units=120, activation='relu'))
    self._regressor.add(Dropout(0.5))
    #this is the output layer
    self._regressor.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

    self._logger.info("TensorFlow Summary\n {}".format(self._regressor.summary()))
    #run regressor
    self._regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy']) 
    self._regressor.fit(data.x_train, data.y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=32)

    data.y_pred_scaled = self._regressor.predict(data.x_test)
    data.y_pred = self._scaler_target.inverse_transform(data.y_pred_scaled)
    scores = self._regressor.evaluate(data.x_test, data.y_test, verbose=0)
```

My issue here is that the output of my prediction has a range of max: 0.5188445 and min: 0.518052, implying to me that all of my classifications are positive (which is definitely incorrect). I even tried predict_classes and this yielded an array of 1's.
I am struggling to find where my issue is despite numerous searches online. I have ensured that my final output layer consists of a sigmoid function as well as included the loss as the binary_crossentropy also. My data has been scaled using sklearn's MinMaxScaler with feature_range=(0,1). I am running my code through a debugger and everything up to the self._regressor.fit looks good so far. I am just struggling with quantifying the output of the predictions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will `epochs=1` make your LSTM converge?

Comment: Hi Han, I actually tried 25 epochs, but due to the time it took to run - i stuck with 1 just for test purposes; prediction values stayed constant

Comment: Have you checked the loss/accuracy? It doesn't seem to learn.

Comment: I believe so, I am running the train on 4480 samples and the loss decreases from around 0.6999 to 0.6909 whilst the accuracy ranges between 0.54 to 0.52. Are these ranges quite common? I've seen examples of people having run these classifiers with their accuracy and loss with static values which suggests no learning is taking place

Comment: Probably not learning. There are many factors that can lead to this problem, so it's hard to say why it is not learning given the information you provided.